# Expo Webview in Production shows ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview, expo

I have a HTML code with injected Javascript which execute and start verification service. It works perfectly fine in development mode, but not in production mode. 
[image: Error on Android at production mode]

```
<WebView
  allowFileAccess={true}
  source={(getSource(file))}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  injectedJavaScript={script}
  originWhitelist={["https://*", "http://*", "file://*", "asset://*"]}

/>


const download = async () => {
  let file = Asset.fromModule(html);
  if (file.localUri !== null) {
    return file
  }
  await file.downloadAsync() // Optional, saves file into cache
  console.log('file', file)
  return file
}

const getSource = (file) => {
  if (Platform.OS !== 'android') {
    return html
  }
  if (file === null) {
    return {}
  }

  return {
    uri: file.localUri
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share a full runnable example? by production mode, do you mean in a standalone app or still in expo client with development mode disabled?

Comment: @brentvatne I have an Expo app. I checked on both in production mode and in development mode, and also installed .apk file. What do you need from code, so I can share with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this [tutorial](http://%20https://medium.com/@filipedegrazia/embedding-a-local-website-on-your-expo-react-native-project-eea322738872) I had the same issue. First you need to change the location of the file on android because in the standalone the file is under `android_assets`. So even though the localuri says one thing, it's not actually at that location.

And you need to make sure that you are bundling the html files as well when it builds. Everything works fine in the expo app because you are accessing things locally but that's not the case once you build the standalone app. I hope this helps. Took me a week to finally get things to work and that article helped.

Comment: Hi Garret, thanks for your contribution, can you please add the code from the blog post into your answer. somtimes external links are lost and the answer becomes invalid in the future.

Comment: Thanks, Garrett for answer. Will follow this link.

Comment: If someone will face with this issue, you can follow this link or ask for help, because I spent many time on that. :) [link] https://medium.com/@filipedegrazia/embedding-a-local-website-on-your-expo-react-native-project-eea322738872